# Bayesian Network with pomegranate

Tags: python, networking, bayesian

I'm testing the code in the pomegranate home page, and I'm obteining getting

```
from pomegranate import *

guest = DiscreteDistribution({'A': 1./3, 'B': 1./3, 'C': 1./3})
prize = DiscreteDistribution({'A': 1./3, 'B': 1./3, 'C': 1./3})
monty = ConditionalProbabilityTable(
        [['A', 'A', 'A', 0.0],
         ['A', 'A', 'B', 0.5],
         ['A', 'A', 'C', 0.5],
         ['A', 'B', 'A', 0.0],
         ['A', 'B', 'B', 0.0],
         ['A', 'B', 'C', 1.0],
         ['A', 'C', 'A', 0.0],
         ['A', 'C', 'B', 1.0],
         ['A', 'C', 'C', 0.0],
         ['B', 'A', 'A', 0.0],
         ['B', 'A', 'B', 0.0],
         ['B', 'A', 'C', 1.0],
         ['B', 'B', 'A', 0.5],
         ['B', 'B', 'B', 0.0],
         ['B', 'B', 'C', 0.5],
         ['B', 'C', 'A', 1.0],
         ['B', 'C', 'B', 0.0],
         ['B', 'C', 'C', 0.0],
         ['C', 'A', 'A', 0.0],
         ['C', 'A', 'B', 1.0],
         ['C', 'A', 'C', 0.0],
         ['C', 'B', 'A', 1.0],
         ['C', 'B', 'B', 0.0],
         ['C', 'B', 'C', 0.0],
         ['C', 'C', 'A', 0.5],
         ['C', 'C', 'B', 0.5],
         ['C', 'C', 'C', 0.0]], [guest, prize])

s1 = Node(guest, name="guest")
s2 = Node(prize, name="prize")
s3 = Node(monty, name="monty")

model = BayesianNetwork("Monty Hall Problem")
model.add_states(s1, s2, s3)
model.add_edge(s1, s3)
model.add_edge(s2, s3)
model.bake()
```

And this is the error:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 3, in <module>
> guest = DiscreteDistribution({'A': 1./3, 'B': 1./3, 'C': 1./3})
> NameError: name 'DiscreteDistribution' is not defined"
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Validate the Output of `print( os.path.dirname(pomegranate.__file__))` with the Output of `pip show pomegranate.py`.